# gwt hosted mode hangs on connecting to 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-hosted-mode

i am using gwt for a while (pretty nice and useful thing)

when i run the hosted mode i am getting the hosted browser window, and it hangs
on "connecting to 127.0.0.1", only after few tires it works well.

anyone encountered this behavior?

please advise

oops forgot to mention that i am using windows XP, GWT 3.5, and eclipse version Galileo

Comment: What version of GWT are you using, which OS, etc?

Comment: Current GWT SDK is version 1.7.1. I'd say that 3.5 is your Eclipse version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hosted mode has issues connecting if the RAM available is running low. Restart your browser and Eclipse and try again.

Next time it happens to you check the amount of left free RAM to confirm this.